# Unable to connect to a directory directly in samba drive location - NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME

Tags: linux, samba, smbclient, smb2

When i try to connect to the location directly using the smbclient I get "NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME".

```
naveenp@LTIN123456:~$ smbclient //sambahost/folder1/folder2/folder3 -U username@sambahost -m SMB2
Password for [username@sambahost]:
tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME
```

where as when i connect to one of the folder in the root of the samba, I can get into and can access the file with cds.

```
naveenp@LTIN123456:~$ smbclient //sambahost/folder1/ -U username@sambahost -m SMB2
Password for [username@sambahost]:
Try "help" to get a list of possible commands.
smb: \> cd folder2\folder3\
smb: \folder2\folder3\> ls
  .                                   D        0  Wed Sep 27 17:29:23 2023
  ..                                  D        0  Wed Sep 27 17:29:23 2023
  File09-27-2023_03-09-04.csv      A   479638  Wed Sep 27 12:30:22 2023

                129184287 blocks of size 65536. 23724791 blocks available
smb: \folder2\folder3\>
```

I'd like to know what could be the reason and workaround for this to get into the directory directly. Thanks very much in advance for all your inputs.

Comment: Note your use of forward slash and backslash. Could it be that on the Windows PC, it needs the backslash to reach folders 2 & 3?

Comment: Thanks for your response @DrMoishePippik I'm trying from ubuntu terminal and when i try using backslash I get ` Not enough '\' characters in service`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`smbclient` requires the "servicename" of an SMB resource (the shared folder) in `//server/service` format. A specific initial directory can be specified with `-D|--directory`:

```
smbclient //sambahost/folder1/ -D folder2/folder3 -U username@sambahost -m SMB2
```